# context.WithDeadline while passing context to go routine?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

context.WithDeadline while passing context to go routine?

I have put together some sample code that will start a new goroutine for every item in my slice.
At the moment, this will wait for the done channel to be called len(slice) times.

However, I would also like to implement a timeout in the goroutines to event leaking.
It seems that context.WithDeadline (or maybe WithTimeout?)is the appropriate function to use.

For example, lets say I want to pass in a 23 second deadline for all goroutines that are initialized from main().
However, its not clear to me how I should do this.

I have read godoc along with [Go Concurrency Patterns: Context (on the go blog)](https://blog.golang.org/context)  but as a new gopher, 
I am none the wiser. Many of the examples that I have found use http.handler(or similar as examples and so they are a source of some confusion for me.

What is an appropriate way to pass in context with deadline / timeout here.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "time"
)

func sleepNow(i int, done chan bool) {
  time.Sleep(time.Duration(i) * time.Second)
  fmt.Println(i, "has just woken up from sleep and the time is", time.Now())

  done <- true
}

func main() {
  done := make(chan bool)
  numbersSlice := []int{10, 20, 30, 12}

  for _, v := range(numbersSlice){
    go sleepNow(v, done)
  }

  for x := 0; x < len(numbersSlice); x++ {
  <-done
  }
  fmt.Println("Looks like we are all done here!")

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is get the context into the function where you want to use it. In many cases you can use a simple closure, or in this case, add it to the function arguments.

Once you have the context in place, you can select on the `Context.Done()` channel to determine when it has expired.

https://play.golang.org/p/q-n_2mIW2X

```
func sleepNow(i int, ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()

    select {
    case <-time.After(time.Duration(i) * time.Second):
        fmt.Println(i, "has just woken up from sleep and the time is", time.Now())
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println(i, "has just been canceled")
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    numbersSlice := []int{1, 5, 4, 2}

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 3*time.Second)

    for _, v := range numbersSlice {
        wg.Add(1)
        go sleepNow(v, ctx, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    cancel()

    fmt.Println("Looks like we are all done here!")
}
```

You should also use a `sync.WaitGroup` rather than rely on counting tokens over channel, and use defer to call Done.